# ASP.NET 5.0 and Visual Studio 2015: Create new fails

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I am attempting to spin up my 1st ASP.NET 5.0 site using Visual Studio 2015 running on Win 10.  I followed the install directions found [here](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/getting-started/installing-on-windows.html)

When I create a new ASP.NET site, the templates generate fine, but the references fail:

[image]

and in the Output has this:
Could not find a part of the path '.dnx\packages\System.Reflection.Emit.ILGeneration\4.0.0\System.Reflection.Emit.ILGeneration.4.0.0.nupkg.sha512'.

Does anyone have an idea?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Silly question: Are you connected to the interwebs?

Comment: What version of Visual Studio and the Web Dev Tools extension do you have installed?  Can you share some information about the contents of your project.json file so that we can investigate?

Answer (score 0):

Try running the following NuGet command in the Visual Studio command line:

```
nuget install packages.config
```

The once the packages are install, update your solution.

```
nuget update solution.sln
```

Comment: I get an 'not recognized as an internal or external command.'  Do I have to be somewhere in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0 ?